# How to define class inheritance with Puppet Ruby DSL

Tags: ruby, configuration-management, puppet

I have a Puppet class "Ruby":

```
# init.pp
class ruby {
  package { 'libldap-ruby1.8':
    ensure => 'installed'
  }
}
```

Then I have a class written in Puppet Ruby DSL, which should inherit this Puppet-class:

```
# ldap.rb
hostclass 'ruby::ldap' do
  (...)
end
```

How do I define that ruby::ldap inherits ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Puppet developers on Google Groups do not answer any related questions ([link1](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/puppet-users/RtMbu8yFZCc/discussion), [link2](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/puppet-users/6RbsbakI2J0/discussion)).

Comment: Maybe you'd have better luck opening an issue requesting some class inheritance examples at https://github.com/bobsh/puppet-rubydsl-examples

Comment: Good idea. I created an issue on Github: https://github.com/bobsh/puppet-rubydsl-examples/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

[Update](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-dev/UsDaDGAneEE), the existing ruby-dsl is deprecated. There exists plans to release a new version that's not backwards compatible. I don't think the older ruby-dsl ever supported inheritance.

If you like the flexibility provided by the puppet ruby-dsl you may enjoy chef as well.

Comment: Thanks. For the reference, this is the link to the discussion about the Ruby DSL: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/puppet-dev/UsDaDGAneEE And for sure I'll have a look at Chef and also Ansible ;)

Comment: Issue about the deprecation of the Ruby DSL: https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/18876